# Making unique profiles for each user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make unique profiles according to the id in the URL but I'm currently getting a "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined" error. This is what I have so far:

```
router.get('/profile/:id', (req,res)=>{
    const Profile = req.params.id
    res.render('profile', {Profile: Profile})
})
```

And in profile.ejs:

```
<h1><%= Profile.email %></h1>
<p><%= Profile.name %></p>
<p><%= Profile.gender %></p>
<p><%= Profile.age %> years old</p>
```

I think the problem is that the ejs file is basically reading something like "60b6302146bcb94c14cbc3c4.email" which is why it doesn't recognize it, but I'm not sure what else I can do.

Edit: I've tried using findOne() but it's still giving a "Cannot read property 'email' of null" error. I don't think I'm using this right.

```
router.get("/profile/:id", function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({
      id: req.params.id
    }, function (err, foundUser) {
      if (err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        return res.redirect("/");
      }
      res.render('profile', {
        Profile: foundUser
      });
    })
});
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the object from mongo based on the id?

Comment: My user schema is like this

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 gender: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
 },
 age: {
  type: Number,
  required: false
 },

Comment: But you will have to query your object right. That is something you haven't done. Profile should not be req.params.id, check how to findeById() or findOne() in mongo and assign the returned object to Person.

Comment: That makes sense! However I've tried using findOne() but it's still giving me an error. I edited my original post with the new code, if you can have a look at that I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: console.log(foundUser) first. Anything you want to check you have to debug like that.

Comment: Hmm, it's saying it's null. Is "id: req.params.id" wrong?

Comment: Just check if the object even exists in the mongo DB.

Comment: Ahhhhh, it's _id, not id.... Thank you for the help!!

Comment: use ```_id: req.params.id```